# WPF DataGrid обновление значения

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть DataGrid в котором отображаются объекты из ObservableCollection.

В момент CellEditingEnding должно меняться поле и вызываться метод по расчету из колонок. в xaml все Bindings указаны. Работает через раз. То есть :
допустим в необходимом нам поле указано значение : 1
если поменять на 2 он посчитает так как будто там было 1
если указать любое другое значение он посчитает так как было бы если там была 2 и так далее

DataGrid.Items.Refresh нельзя использовать внутри CellEditingEnding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите`UpdateSourceTrigger` в значение `PropertyChanged`, там, где вы привязываетесь к полям объекта:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Вы очень сильно помогли, спасибо Вам огромное. Я уже читал про кастомизацию коллекции, переработку модели, нигде нету ответа в интернетах.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, пожалуйста. Да, иногда можно далеко уйти в поисках решения, когда оно совсем рядом.